# Multiple constructor parameter injection in php-di

Tags: php, php-di

I'm trying to use [PHP-DI](http://php-di.org), but I did not quite succeed.
In my simple scanario, a controller, in a *Wordpress Theme*, needs a PostService and a CategoryService injected in constructor:

```php
class IndexController extends ChesterBaseController {
    private $_postservice;
    private $_categoryService;
    public function __construct(PostService $postservice, CategoryService $categoryService){
        var_dump($postservice);
        var_dump($categoryService);
        parent::__CONSTRUCT();
        $this->$_categoryService = $categoryService;
        $this->$_postservice = $postservice;
        var_dump($this->$_postservice);
        var_dump($this->$_categoryService);

    }
    public function Index(){
        $firstRowPost = $this->$_postservice->GetLastPostByCategory('video');
        // ...
        echo $this->renderPage('index', $vm);
    }
}
```

This is my entry point for the container in the Index.php:

```php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/mvc/controllers/index_controller.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/mvc/services/categoryService.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/mvc/services/postService.php';
use DI\Container;
use DI\ContainerBuilder;

$builder = new DI\ContainerBuilder();
$builder->addDefinitions(['config.php']);
$container = $builder->build();
$indexController = $container->get('IndexController');
$indexController->Index();
```

And the 'config.php' which contains the definitions:

```php
return [
    'PostService' => \DI\object('PostService'),
    'CategoryService' => \DI\object('CategoryService'),
    'IndexController' => \DI\object()->constructor(DI\get('PostService'),DI\get('CategoryService'))
];
```

This is the execution result:

> C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\themes\chester-nanalab\mvc\controllers\index_controller.php:10:
>   object(PostService)[3005]
>   C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\themes\chester-nanalab\mvc\controllers\index_controller.php:11:
>   object(CategoryService)[3006]
>   C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\themes\chester-nanalab\mvc\controllers\index_controller.php:15:
>   object(CategoryService)[3006]
>   C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\themes\chester-nanalab\mvc\controllers\index_controller.php:16:
>   object(CategoryService)[3006]

and so:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   CategoryService::GetLastPostByCategory() in
>   C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\themes\chester-nanalab\mvc\controllers\index_controller.php
>   on line 19

[ლ(ಠ益ಠლ)╯](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)

but, if I change the order of the assignments:

```php
public function __construct(PostService $postservice,CategoryService $categoryService){
    var_dump($postservice);
    var_dump($categoryService);
    parent::__CONSTRUCT();
    $this->$_categoryService = $categoryService;
    $this->$_postservice = $postservice;
    var_dump($this->$_postservice);
    var_dump($this->$_categoryService);
}
```

I can read:

> C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\themes\chester-nanalab\mvc\controllers\index_controller.php:10:
>   object(PostService)[3005]
>   C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\themes\chester-nanalab\mvc\controllers\index_controller.php:11:
>   object(CategoryService)[3006]
>   C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\themes\chester-nanalab\mvc\controllers\index_controller.php:17:
>   object(PostService)[3005]
>   C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\themes\chester-nanalab\mvc\controllers\index_controller.php:18:
>   object(PostService)[3005]

[image]

[(╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)? It works!
Can anyone explain to me what is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are calling `$this->$_categoryService = $categoryService;` and `$this->$_postservice = $postservice;`, you should be calling `$this->_categoryService` and `$this->_postservice`

Comment: thanks @matiaslauriti, unfortunatelly this is just my second day on php, you are right, please add your answer so that I can accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling an object property as `$this->$property`. Properties are accessed like this `$this->property` but defined `VISIBILITY $property;`

So, you should change your code to this

```php
class IndexController extends ChesterBaseController {
    private $_postservice;
    private $_categoryService;
    public function __construct(PostService $postservice, CategoryService $categoryService){
      var_dump($postservice);
      var_dump($categoryService);
      parent::__construct();
      $this->_categoryService = $categoryService;
      $this->_postservice = $postservice;
      var_dump($this->_postservice);
      var_dump($this->_categoryService);

    }
    public function Index(){
        $firstRowPost = $this->_postservice->GetLastPostByCategory('video');
       // ...
        echo $this->renderPage('index', $vm);
    }
}
```

For `parent` it is different, because you are using `static` accessor (you are not getting the property as static, but it is the way to do it) `parent::$property`.

And remember, it is `__construct` in lowercase for any [magic method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php).

You can have more info for Classes and Objects [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php).

Comment: glad to learn something new Matias, thanks a lot! All the best.

Comment: Also please note that `$builder->addDefinitions(['config.php'])` is not valid, it should be `$builder->addDefinitions('config.php')`.

Comment: @InferOn I am really happy to help, the PHP documentation is pretty extensive and good, so remember to have a look there, you will find anything :D

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli Thanks for pointing that out. I don't know anything about Wordpress, so thank you.

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli you are right, and thanks for your work on php-di